# How to limit questions in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I use flutter and php, and i need to get only 40 random questions from database, but i am beginner in php! How i can do it? See code bellow

```
public function index(){

$user = Auth::user();
$topics = Topic::all()->toArray();
$questions = Question::all()->toArray();

    return response()->json(array('users' =>$user,'topics'=>$topics,'questions'=>$questions), 200);

// return response()->json(['data' => $posts], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

public function show_question($id){
    $topic = Topic::findOrFail($id);
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $existing = Answer::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('topic_id',$id)->first();
    if($existing == ""){
        $topic_ques = Question::where('topic_id', $id)->get()->shuffle(); 
        $questions = $topic_ques->only(40);
        return response()->json(array('topic'=>$topic,'questions' => $questions), 200);
    }
    else{
      return response()->json("test already given", 300);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$questions = Question::where('topic_id', $id)->inRandomOrder()->take(40)->get();
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function index(){

$user = Auth::user();
$topics = Topic::all()->toArray();
$questions = Question::all()->random(40)->toArray();

    return response()->json(array('users' =>$user,'topics'=>$topics,'questions'=>$questions), 200);

// return response()->json(['data' => $posts], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

public function show_question($id){
    $topic = Topic::findOrFail($id);
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $existing = Answer::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('topic_id',$id)->first();
    if($existing == ""){
        $topic_ques = Question::where('topic_id', $id)->get()->shuffle(); 
        $questions = $topic_ques->only(40);
        return response()->json(array('topic'=>$topic,'questions' => $questions), 200);
    }
    else{
      return response()->json("test already given", 300);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $topic_ques = Question::where('topic_id', $id)->limit(40)->get()->shuffle();
```

Just use the limit function.

Comment: that won't bring random

Comment: You're shuffling the order of first 40 questions not fetching 40 random questions.